# Alter values of xAxis in chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to make a logarithmic chart, and here the full example of what I tried:

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-frog-qnqvii?file=/App.tsx:346-357

What I still need is to display the xAxis with a step of 2 like in this chart:

[image]

Please notice that the max value of the chart grid is '26' and not '24' and the min value is `10` instead of `12`.

How can I acheive this ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
...
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: "logarithmic",
      min: 12,
      max: 24
    },
...
```